# async/await prevents Angular2 from rendering the component when used in template statement

Tags: async-await, angular

The following method will be executed when clicking a button of a component.

```
async onClickButton() {
    await this.shoppingCartService.add(this.selectedOffer);
    this.router.navigate(['ShoppingCartComponent']);
}
```

The data will be added to the shopping cart, but upon navigating to the next page only the title will be rendered, the data won't. This method works and the following page will correctly be rendered if not using async-await.
Forcing change detection with ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() and ApplicationRef.tick() have no effect.
After leaving the next page i.e. ShoppingCartComponent the rendering takes place and for a moment the data will be displayed.
Any ideas what could go wrong?

Comment: Hve you tried it in Angular 2.4.8 ?? ..cause in 2.4.4 it worked for me..now i update Angular to 2.4.8 ..and it doesn't work again (only woth this.ngZone.run .. but it sucks!!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue of `async`/`await`. It causes code following `await` not to run inside Angulars zone.

As workaround you would need to inject `NgZone` in the constructor and change your code to

```
async onClickButton() {
    await this.shoppingCartService.add(this.selectedOffer);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['ShoppingCartComponent']);
    });
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/322

Comment: Now works fine (without ngZone.run) in Angular v2.4.4+.

Comment: @RodolfoJorgeNemerNogueira thanks for the feedback. Wow longest SO user name I ever saw :D

Comment: Hi ..is possible that is starting again to doesn't work in Angular 2.4.8 ?? ..cause in 2.4.4 it was working ..now i update angular..and again works only with this.ngZone.run :-( ..sich!!

Comment: What do you mean with "starting again"? Do you mean it stopped working again?

Comment: Yes!! ... i have updated angular to 2.4.8 and node.js to the latest ( 7.6.0)

Comment: Did you check GitHub issues if a related bug was reported?

Comment: Mmm no... can you share me the link?

Comment: It is really stringe.. now i try with the angular 2.4.4 ( the old project that worked) .. and it doesn't.. i really can't understand why.. possibile node.js update? ( from 7.2.0 to 7.6.0??)