# Access constructor parameters inside the google sign in function Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, google-signin

I translate google sign in javascript to typescript, and it works, the issue I'm having is I cannot access to _router variable inside the google sign in function. Inside attachSignin() function I try to access _router: Router param from the constructor and I get that is undefinded.

this is my code

```
import {Component, NgZone} from "angular2/core";
import {ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import {Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'

// Google's login API namespace
declare var gapi: any;

@Component({
    selector: "sous-app",
    templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
    providers: [ToastsManager, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class Login {
    googleLoginButtonId = "google-login-button";
    userAuthToken = null;
    userDisplayName = "empty";
    auth2 = null;
    self = this;


    constructor(
        public _router: Router) { }

    // Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
    // rendering of a view.
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var loginProxy = $.proxy(this.attachSignin, this);
        var redirectToPolls = $.proxy(this.redirectToPolls, this);
        gapi.load('auth2', function () {
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            self.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '718161509287-jdpqsuebcoteh847krjn0m1odnbo5i3q.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                //scope: 'additional_scope'
            });
            loginProxy(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
        });

    }


    attachSignin = (element) => {

        var navigate = false;
        console.log(element.id);
        self.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            function (googleUser) {

                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

                //HERE I WANT TO ACCESS ROUTER
                _router.navigate(['Polls']);



                console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);



            }, function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `function()` to `() =>`

```
    self.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        (googleUser) => {
```

Comment: Now It does not gave me an undefined it change the browser url but doesn't navigate to it. How can I force the navigation?

Comment: This should work for you as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/36171639/217408 Wrap the code in the callback that gets called by the google library in `zone.run(...)`

Comment: Why do I have to use the function like that or use zones, is there something I can read about it?

Comment: `=>` is a JS feature https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions, Angular uses zones for change detection and external libraries like Google login can cause code to leave Angulars zone and "break" change detection http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: No luck :(, I use this.zone.run(() => this._router.navigate['Polls']); instead of _router.navigate(['Polls']); in the code given in the question. Doesn't give me an error, It just do nothin.

Comment: Ensure you have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` **only once** at the root component or in `bootstrap(...)`?

Comment: Yes, just on the root, I have the same issue using Auth0. I contact them and they told me: use HTTP redirect from within a Rule, if the Rule detects a certain condition. One possible use is to redirect to an explanatory page if a certain error condition is detected, such as the user's email has not been validated.

The rule code to issue a redirect is:

function (user, context, callback) {

context.redirect = {
//Redirect to jwt.io site as an example
url: "http://jwt.io"
};

Comment: But that's not using router. I don't know what is the best aprouch.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You use `router.navigate()` and the router doesn't work if `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are added to several components. It should be provided only once at the root.

Comment: I've re ckecked and I just have the ROUTER_PROVIDERS on the main component, just there.

Comment: I found why it does not navigate, when it calls the navigate for some reason inside that method does not hash the url eg /#/polls just put /polls it doesn't break but it's not a valid url so it just stays there. It has to be something realated with the call inside the gmail login method because I'm using the navigate in other places and it hashes the url. There's some way to make the call and add the hash?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is related to Angulars zone. You inject `NgZone` using the constructor?

Comment: This is my constructor     constructor(zone: NgZone, private _router: Router) {

    }

Comment: I have ROUTER_PROVIDERS twise in my app, I have checked again. Now it's navigating correctly.

Comment: That can only be despite `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` twice, not because of it :D. Where do you have it? Two components? Or `bootstrap()` and a component? Or did you mean, you *had* it twice and now it's working because you removed it at one place?